# How can I filter a string array in ng-repeat with another string array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select element that I want to filter:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="span2" data-ng-model="selectedParameters">
    <option data-ng-repeat="parameter in availableParameters">
        {{parameter}}
    </option>
</select>
```

"availableParameters" is a string array that I can reach from here without problem, and "selectedParameters" is another string array that represents the selected elements in the UI.

```
availableParameters = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];
```

I have another string array under object graph (accessible inside the HTML)

```
graph.parameters = ["AAA", "BBB"];
```

I am trying to filter "availableParameters" by "graph.parameters" and obtain a list like this: "CCC", "DDD"

I checked AngularJS's documentation but couldn't see an example for my problem.

All I could do is something like this:

```
<option data-ng-repeat="parameter in availableParameters | filter: !graph.parameters ">{{parameter}}</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a custom filter to filter out all of the items that aren't in `graph.parameters`:

```
angular.module('yourModuleNameHere').filter('params', [function(){
    return function (items, filterBy) {
      return items.filter(function(currentItem){
        return filterBy.indexOf(currentItem) === -1;
      });
    };
}]);
```

Afterwards you can use it as:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="span2" data-ng-model="selectedParameters">
    <option data-ng-repeat="parameter in availableParameters | params:graph.parameters">
        {{parameter}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways, a filter is useful when the data can change but I think that isn't your case, you just need to add a simple business login in your controller... have a look on what follows:

```js
var rawlist = ['foo', 'baz', 'bar'];
var blacklist = ['baz'];

var list = rawlist.filter(function(item) {
  return blacklist.indexOf(item) < 0;
});

console.log('available parameters are', list);
```

so, your view can be:

```html
<select ng-model="someScopeProperty" ng-options="item for item in list track by $index"></select>
```